# Laptop Blender Comand Hotkeys

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Good evening my 3D Animation Wizards,
I'm new here
My Name is Dee.

I'm severely new to blender, my issue is that everytime I watch a tuturial on youtube, I get lost with the hotkeys because everyone is using their desktop for the hotkeys. I have a laptop and I get so irratated.

Does anyone know all of the laptop hotkeys for blender?

Comment: They are the same exact ones as desktop, there are no specific keys or presets for desktop or laptos. Only difference is if you don't have a full keyboard with a numpad for which there is an option in *Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad* which may come in handy

Comment: I had the same frustration as you, Dee, and the way I solved it was to go get an inexpensive full sized USB keyboard (in the US, for about $10.00 or so), and connect it to my laptop when I wanted to use Blender. In my own partucicular case, the full sized keyboard was easier to use for me, not only for Blender, but other applications as well, that I simply used that whenever I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking specifically about numpad commands, since I'm assuming that's really the only difference between a typical laptop and a desktop keyboard.

Go to user preferences > input and look for a checkbox that says 'emulate numpad'. This will turn your number key row into a numpad.

Here's a screenshot of the setting on the left side:

[image]